# Can I get a call back to my VF page when I call ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem in my Apex class

Tags: apex, visualforce, chatter, connect-api

I am trying to post to a chatter feed from my Visual Force page. I am using a custom implementation of the chatter feed so I am using an input box and a Command link to try to post to the chatter feed.

Here is the code in my Visual Force page:

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:inputText value="{!feedItemInputText}"/>
    <apex:commandLink reRender="feedOutputPanel" action="{!postNewFeedItem}" value="Post">           
     </apex:commandLink>
    </apex:form>
```

And here is the code in my APEX class:

```
public void postNewFeedItem() {
    // Post to the chatter news feed.
    ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.Record, RecordId, feedItemInputText);
 }
```

This all works as expected. However on my Visual Force page I have to refresh it to see the newly added post in my Chatter feed. Is there a call back or some way to tell my Visual Force page that the postFeedItem function has completed successfully and that I can now refresh my Visual Force page?

Or is there some other way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it like this,
`public PageReference postNewFeedItem() {
    PageReference PageRef=Page.pageyouwanttorefresh;
    // Post to the chatter news feed.
    ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.Record, RecordId,feedItemInputText);
    PageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return PageRef;
 }`

Comment: It works as in it refreshes the page but I also need to send an ID in the URL of the page, I have tried PageReference PageRef=Page.pageyouwanttorefresh+'id'; But the compiler doesn't like it, I guess it may not be possible to send an id to the page this way?

Comment: true, for sending parameters you need to construct your PageReference like this, PageReference Page=new PageReference('/pageyouwanttorefresh/'+idyouwanttosend). Refer this page for more information,https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_system_pagereference.htm